# jQuery add element dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am adding a div on click function, found this code which is working fine

```
function GetHtml()
{
    var len = $('.extraPerson').length;
    var $html = $('.extraPersonTemplate').clone();

    $html.find('[id=condition]')[0].name="condition[]"; // drop-down
    $html.find('[id=data_type]')[0].name="data_type[]";
    $html.find('[id=filter]')[0].name="filter[]";
    $html.find('[id=detail]')[0].name="detail[]";

    return $html.html();    
}
```

now I want to add more element but with a check

```
IF <new_element> NO EXIST THEN 
$html.find('[id=new_element]')[0].name="new_element[]";
```

but not sure how

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
if( $html.find('[id=new_element]').length == 0 ) {
  // add your element here
}
```

Without more context of what your structure looks like or what you are looking to add I can't be more help.

Additionally, your finds could be simplified to:

```
$("#condition", $html).attr("name", "condition[]"); // drop-down
$("#data_type", $html).attr("name", "data_type[]");
$("#filter", $html).attr("name", "filter[]");
$("#detail", $html).attr("name", "detail[]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
if($html.find('[id=new_element]').Length == 0)
{
    $html.find('[id=new_element]')[0].name="new_element[]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try the code below:

```
if(typeof $("identificate_your_element").get(0) == "undefined"){
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first see what your function is doing and than say what you want.

```
    function GetHtml()
    {
        // Getting length of element with class extraPerson
        var len = $('.extraPerson').length;

        // Making clone of html element having class extraPersonTemplate
        var $html = $('.extraPersonTemplate').clone();

        // Finding html element having ID[condition] inside cloned element and setting name atrribute condition[]
        $html.find('[id=condition]')[0].name="condition[]"; // drop-down
        // Finding html element having ID[extraPersonTemplate] inside cloned element and setting name atrribute data_type[]
        $html.find('[id=data_type]')[0].name="data_type[]";
        // Finding html element having ID[filter] inside cloned element and setting name atrribute filter[]
        $html.find('[id=filter]')[0].name="filter[]";
        // Finding html element having ID[detail] inside cloned element and setting name atrribute detail[]
        $html.find('[id=detail]')[0].name="detail[]";


        //finally returning clone element with setting all the element attribute present inside it
        return $html.html();    
    }
```

here you are cloning a html element and setting name attribute of element which are already present in it

if you have to add new element to it than try something like this

```
IF <new_element> NO EXIST THEN 
    $html.append($('<div>NEW DIV</div>'));
```